# OVH linux vps stuck in rescue mode

Tags: linux, vps

I have tried the fdisk -l command and it shows no drives at all, i tried ls and get nothing, I am pretty new at this so what should i do? the control panel on the site will not allow me to reboot in normal mode, it always falls into rescue mode. i also tried parted -l and nothing. what do i do? here is a copy paste from my current support ticket:

Open on 1/26/15 2:11 AM

From: customer
i had rebooted my server after i couldn't log in through putty, upon the reboot, it booted me into rescue mode. i proceeded to remount the system, but their are no drives present at all..
1/26/15 2:11 AM
From: support
Good day Mr. Desmoines

Thank you for letting us know about this drive issue in rescue mode. I'll gladly guide you with the drive mounting process.

In fact, this is totally normal. When starting in rescue mode, a standard kernel is booted with a temporary file system. To access your drives, you will have to mount them manually.

In order to do so, I would suggest to look into fdisk and mount documentation.

The steps should vaguely look like this but I cannot guarantee this procedure as management is our client's responsibility.

1. List the disks present:
   fdisk -l
2. Find the partition number and the file system type:
   cfdisk /dev/sda
3. Create a temporary mount point:
   mkdir /mnt/temp
4. Mount and access:
   mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/temp
   cd /mnt/temp

Alternatively, you can also follow our documentation about mounting disks in rescue mode:

## mounting-disk-s

I hope this information will allow you access your data while in rescue mode. I will gladly remain at your disposal for any further question!

Thank you for choosing OVH. Have an excellent day!

Pierre D.
Customer Advocate
1/26/15 9:30 AM
From: customer
fdisk doesnt show anything being their.

On Mon, Jan 26, 2015 at 9:55 AM,  wrote:

> Good day Mr. Desmoines
>
> Thank you for letting us know about this drive issue in rescue mode. I'll
>   gladly guide you with the drive mounting process.
>
> In fact, this is totally normal. When starting in rescue mode, a standard
>   kernel is booted with a temporary file system. To access your drives, you
>   will have to mount them manually.
>
> In order to do so, I would suggest to look into fdisk and mount
>   documentation.
>
> The steps should vaguely look like this but I cannot guarantee this
>   procedure as management is our client's responsibility.
>
> 1. List the disks present:
>      fdisk -l
> 2. Find the partition number and the file system type:
>      cfdisk /dev/sda
> 3. Create a temporary mount point:
>      mkdir /mnt/temp
> 4. Mount and access:
>      mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/temp
>      cd /mnt/temp
>
> Alternatively, you can also follow our documentation about mounting disks
>   in rescue mode:
>
> ## mounting-disk-s
>
> I hope this information will allow you access your data while in rescue
>   mode. I will gladly remain at your disposal for any further question!
>
> Thank you for choosing OVH. Have an excellent day!
>
> Pierre D.
>   Customer Advocate

1/26/15 9:56 AM
From: customer
also, i get this..:

FATAL ERROR: Cannot open disk drive
                          Press any key to exit cfdisk

On Mon, Jan 26, 2015 at 9:55 AM, Shade Emry  wrote:

> fdisk doesn't show anything being their.
>
> On Mon, Jan 26, 2015 at 9:55 AM,  wrote:
>
> > Good day Mr. Desmoines
> >
> > Thank you for letting us know about this drive issue in rescue mode. I'll
> >     gladly guide you with the drive mounting process.
> >
> > In fact, this is totally normal. When starting in rescue mode, a standard
> >     kernel is booted with a temporary file system. To access your drives, you
> >     will have to mount them manually.
> >
> > In order to do so, I would suggest to look into fdisk and mount
> >     documentation.
> >
> > The steps should vaguely look like this but I cannot guarantee this
> >     procedure as management is our client's responsibility.
> >
> > 1. List the disks present:
> >        fdisk -l
> > 2. Find the partition number and the file system type:
> >        cfdisk /dev/sda
> > 3. Create a temporary mount point:
> >        mkdir /mnt/temp
> > 4. Mount and access:
> >        mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/temp
> >        cd /mnt/temp
> >
> > Alternatively, you can also follow our documentation about mounting disks
> >     in rescue mode:
> >
> > ## mounting-disk-s
> >
> > I hope this information will allow you access your data while in rescue
> >     mode. I will gladly remain at your disposal for any further question!
> >
> > Thank you for choosing OVH. Have an excellent day!
> >
> > Pierre D.
> >     Customer Advocate

1/26/15 10:03 AM
From: support
Good day again Mr. Desmoines,

Thank you for the quick reply. I'm happy to continue helping you with this issue.

Are you in rescue mode because there was a problem with your VPS? Could you provide some history about the steps you took?

When I was saying this is normal, the disks missing isn't indeed! So, when you type fdisk -l on the prompt in rescue mode you don't have any drives listed, is that correct? If so, I would greatly appreciate if you could show us a screenshot or some text capture. The drives should be there so if they are not, screenshots and steps history would accelerate the escalation process on our side.

Thank you for your patience regarding this drive issue. Please let us know about your progress and do not hesitate to provide any other information. We are open 24/7 and will be happy to provide further assistance.

Thank you for trusting OVH. Have an excellent day!

Pierre D.
Customer Advocate
1/26/15 10:24 AM
From: customer
only steps i took was those found in the documentation, after fdisk -l
didn't list anything, i really couldnt do much more

On Mon, Jan 26, 2015 at 12:07 PM,> wrote:

> Good day again Mr. Desmoines,
>
> Thank you for the quick reply. I'm happy to continue helping you with this
>   issue.
>
> Are you in rescue mode because there was a problem with your VPS? Could
>   you provide some history about the steps you took?
>
> When I was saying this is normal, the disks missing isn't indeed! So, when
>   you type fdisk -l on the prompt in rescue mode you don't have any drives
>   listed, is that correct? If so, I would greatly appreciate if you could
>   show us a screenshot or some text capture. The drives should be there so if
>   they are not, screenshots and steps history would accelerate the escalation
>   process on our side.
>
> Thank you for your patience regarding this drive issue. Please let us know
>   about your progress and do not hesitate to provide any other information.
>   We are open 24/7 and will be happy to provide further assistance.
>
> Thank you for trusting OVH. Have an excellent day!
>
> Pierre D.
>   Customer Advocate

1/26/15 1:54 PM
From: support
Good day again Mr. Desmoines,

The fdisk command will not show any results on a VPS classic.  To check your disk space on a VPS, you can use the command df -h.

You can deposit files on / and paste us the link.

Also, some history as to why you are in rescue mode could also be helpful. Was there any issue with your VPS that made you boot into rescue mode? Was everything running perfectly prior to booting into rescue mode?

I will be waiting for your reply and will remain at your disposal for any other question.

Thank you choosing OVH. Have an outstanding day!

Pierre D.
Customer Advocate
1/26/15 2:21 PM
From: customer
i didn't reboot into rescue mode, i did a generic server restart as i
couldn't log in with putty, so i restarted the server. i got a notification
that i was in rescue mode in my email and yeah.. googled it, found your
documentation and followed it, until the fdisk command... thats when the
drives were not listed . and yes everything was running fine.

On Mon, Jan 26, 2015 at 7:16 PM,  wrote:

> Good day again Mr. Desmoines,
>
> The fdisk command will not show any results on a VPS classic.  To check
>   your disk space on a VPS, you can use the command df -h.
>
> You can deposit files on  and paste us the link.
>
> Also, some history as to why you are in rescue mode could also be helpful.
>   Was there any issue with your VPS that made you boot into rescue mode? Was
>   everything running perfectly prior to booting into rescue mode?
>
> I will be waiting for your reply and will remain at your disposal for any
>   other question.
>
> Thank you choosing OVH. Have an outstanding day!
>
> Pierre D.
>   Customer Advocate

1/26/15 11:10 PM
From: support
Good day Mr. Desmoines,

Thank you for your reply and I wish to say I'm terribly sorry about the confusion. I'll be glad to continue helping you with this rescue mode issue.

But first, just to make sure I understand correctly, you restarted your VPS and it booted into rescue mode without you asking for it?

If this is the case, you can simply go into your Control Panel, click on Infrastructure, select your VPS and click the "Reboot my VPS" button. It will restart the VPS in normal mode and everything should be back on track. It would also be possible to simply type "reboot" on the prompt of the rescue mode.

I would recommend trying to restart into normal mode first. If this happens again or if your VPS keeps rebooting into rescue mode, then could get back to mounting your drives, make a backup and do a hardware test.

Please let me know if a simple reboot will work. I will be waiting for your reply.

Thank you for contacting OVH. Have a great day!

Pierre D.
Customer Advocate
1/27/15 1:29 PM
From: customer
i tried that as well.. it reboots in rescue mode regardless

On Tue, Jan 27, 2015 at 3:24 PM,  wrote:

> Good day Mr. Desmoines,
>
> Thank you for your reply and I wish to say I'm terribly sorry about the
>   confusion. I'll be glad to continue helping you with this rescue mode issue.
>
> But first, just to make sure I understand correctly, you restarted your
>   VPS and it booted into rescue mode without you asking for it?
>
> If this is the case, you can simply go into your Control Panel, click on
>   Infrastructure, select your VPS and click the "Reboot my VPS" button. It
>   will restart the VPS in normal mode and everything should be back on track.
>   It would also be possible to simply type "reboot" on the prompt of the
>   rescue mode.
>
> I would recommend trying to restart into normal mode first. If this
>   happens again or if your VPS keeps rebooting into rescue mode, then could
>   get back to mounting your drives, make a backup and do a hardware test.
>
> Please let me know if a simple reboot will work. I will be waiting for
>   your reply.
>
> Thank you for contacting OVH. Have a great day!
>
> Pierre D.
>   Customer Advocate

1/27/15 5:51 PM
From: support
Good day Mr. Desmoines,

Thank you for the follow-up.

I have verified with our VPS team since yours is stuck in rescue mode. They have tried to reboot it into normal mode but it refuses to do so.

So we are unfortunately back to square one, that is, accessing your disk, make a backup and reinstall the VPS. I have also made inquiries about the fdisk -l command not giving any results and it could be because the partition table is in GPT format, which is incompatible with fdisk. The command compatible with the GPT format, that would allow you to list your disks and partition, is parted -l.

The rest of the procedure will be the same. List the drives, find the right partition, mount it, backup your data with SSH/SCP or FTP then reinstall your VPS.

Here is again the link to our guide to mount a partition in rescue mode.

## mounting-disk-s

Just replace "fdisk -l" with "parted -l" and follow the rest of the guide.

I apologize again for this inconvenience and can only wish you can get back to a working VPS. I thank you for your extreme patience and do not hesitate to reply to this ticket if any other issue arises.

Thank you for choosing OVH. Have a great day!

Pierre D.
Customer Advocate
1/28/15 2:51 PM
From: customer
can i get credit for the downtime i have incurred?

On Wed, Jan 28, 2015 at 3:08 PM,  wrote:

> Good day Mr. Desmoines,
>
> Thank you for the follow-up.
>
> I have verified with our VPS team since yours is stuck in rescue mode.
>   They have tried to reboot it into normal mode but it refuses to do so.
>
> So we are unfortunately back to square one, that is, accessing your disk,
>   make a backup and reinstall the VPS. I have also made inquiries about the
>   fdisk -l command not giving any results and it could be because the
>   partition table is in GPT format, which is incompatible with fdisk. The
>   command compatible with the GPT format, that would allow you to list your
>   disks and partition, is parted -l.
>
> The rest of the procedure will be the same. List the drives, find the
>   right partition, mount it, backup your data with SSH/SCP or FTP then
>   reinstall your VPS.
>
> Here is again the link to our guide to mount a partition in rescue mode.
>   http://docs.ovh.ca/en/guides-ovh-rescue.html#mounting-disk-s
>   Just replace "fdisk -l" with "parted -l" and follow the rest of the guide.
>
> I apologize again for this inconvenience and can only wish you can get
>   back to a working VPS. I thank you for your extreme patience and do not
>   hesitate to reply to this ticket if any other issue arises.
>
> Thank you for choosing OVH. Have a great day!
>
> Pierre D.
>   Customer Advocate

1/28/15 4:35 PM
From: customer
its ubunto 14.04, this is the error i got regarding trying  to use the
parted command

On Wed, Jan 28, 2015 at 4:35 PM, Shade Emry  wrote:

> can i get credit for the downtime i have incurred?
>
> On Wed, Jan 28, 2015 at 3:08 PM,  wrote:
>
> > Good day Mr. Desmoines,
> >
> > Thank you for the follow-up.
> >
> > I have verified with our VPS team since yours is stuck in rescue mode.
> >     They have tried to reboot it into normal mode but it refuses to do so.
> >
> > So we are unfortunately back to square one, that is, accessing your disk,
> >     make a backup and reinstall the VPS. I have also made inquiries about the
> >     fdisk -l command not giving any results and it could be because the
> >     partition table is in GPT format, which is incompatible with fdisk. The
> >     command compatible with the GPT format, that would allow you to list your
> >     disks and partition, is parted -l.
> >
> > The rest of the procedure will be the same. List the drives, find the
> >     right partition, mount it, backup your data with SSH/SCP or FTP then
> >     reinstall your VPS.
> >
> > Here is again the link to our guide to mount a partition in rescue mode.
> >     http://docs.ovh.ca/en/guides-ovh-rescue.html#mounting-disk-s
> >     Just replace "fdisk -l" with "parted -l" and follow the rest of the guide.
> >
> > I apologize again for this inconvenience and can only wish you can get
> >     back to a working VPS. I thank you for your extreme patience and do not
> >     hesitate to reply to this ticket if any other issue arises.
> >
> > Thank you for choosing OVH. Have a great day!
> >
> > Pierre D.
> >     Customer Advocate

Comment: ...aren't OVH VPSes all OpenVZ-based? Those don't _have_ actual disks. Or do they offer several kinds?